# Issues saving and restoring tensorflow model (LSTM)

Tags: tensorflow, restore, lstm, recurrent-neural-network

I'm working on an LSTM that generates text and I'm having issues reusing previously trained models. I've broken down my code below while using the [tensorflow website](https://www.tensorflow.org/programmers_guide/variables) as a resource.

Here I establish all of my variables:

```
graph = tf.Graph()

with graph.as_default():
    global_step = tf.Variable(0)

    data = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [batch_size, len_section, char_size])
    labels = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [batch_size, char_size])

    .....

    #Reset at the beginning of each test
    reset_test_state = tf.group(test_output.assign(tf.zeros([1, hidden_nodes])), 
                                test_state.assign(tf.zeros([1, hidden_nodes])))

    #LSTM
    test_output, test_state = lstm(test_data, test_output, test_state)
    test_prediction = tf.nn.softmax(tf.matmul(test_output, w) + b)

    saver = tf.train.Saver()
```

Here, I am training my model and saving a checkpoint at 30 iterations

```
with tf.Session(graph = graph) as sess:
    tf.global_variables_initializer().run()
    offset = 0

    for step in range(10000):

        offset = offset % len(X)

        if offset <= (len(X) - batch_size):

            batch_data = X[offset: offset + batch_size]
            batch_labels = y[offset:offset+batch_size]
            offset += batch_size

        else: 
            to_add = batch_size - (len(X) - offset)
            batch_data = np.concatenate((X[offset: len(X)], X[0: to_add]))
            batch_labels = np.concatenate((y[offset: len(X)], y[0: to_add]))
            offset = to_add

        _, training_loss = sess.run([optimizer, loss], feed_dict = {data : batch_data, labels : batch_labels})

        if step % 10 == 0:
            print('training loss at step %d: %.2f (%s)' % (step, training_loss, datetime.datetime.now()))

        if step % save_every == 0:
            saver.save(sess, checkpoint_directory + '/model.ckpt', global_step=step)

        if step == 30:
            break
```

I look at that directory and the following files were created:

[image]

Here I am supposedly restoring my trained model and testing it:

```
with tf.Session(graph=graph) as sess:
    #standard init step
    offset = 0
    saver = tf.train.Saver()
    saver.restore(sess, "/ckpt/model-150.meta")
    tf.global_variables_initializer().run()

    test_start = "I plan to make this world a better place "
    test_generated = test_start

....
```

After doing this I get the following error:

```
DataLossError (see above for traceback): Unable to open table file /ckpt/model.ckpt-30.meta: Data loss: not an sstable (bad magic number): perhaps your file is in a different file format and you need to use a different restore operator?
```

I'm not quite sure what i'm doing wrong. The tutorial seems pretty straightforward but I'm obviously missing something. Any sort of feedback would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, note that if you initialize all variables after restoring from a checkpoint you will get their random initial values instead of the trained values.

Second, it's much easier to get saving / restoring right if you use `tf.estimator.Estimator` instead of implementing this yourself.

Third, I don't understand how you're passing `model-150.meta` to restore but seeing an error about `model-30.meta`. I believe, though, you should pass only `model-30` (without the .meta suffix).